# Monty Hall problem with coin flip

Tags: combinatorics, conditional-probability, monty-hall

> Before each show, Monty secretly flips a coin with probability p of Heads. If the coin
>   lands Heads, Monty resolves to open a goat door (with equal probabilities if there is
>   a choice). Otherwise, Monty resolves to open a random unopened door, with equal probabilities. The contestant knows p but does not know the outcome of the coin flip.
>   When the show starts, the contestant chooses a door. Monty (who knows where the car is) then opens a door. If the car is revealed, the game is over; if a goat is revealed, the contestant is offered the option of switching. Now suppose it turns out that the contestant opens door 1 and then Monty opens door 2, revealing a goat. What is the contestant’s probability of success if he or she switches to door 3?

This is from "Introduction to Probability" By Joseph K. Blitzstein

The solution that I came up with is the following:

Ci - event that car is behind door i

H - event that coin landed head

Xi - event that participant picks door i initially
Oi - event that Monty opens door i

Given this we have:

$P(C3|X1, O2) = \frac{P(O2|C3, X1)P(C3|X1)}{P(O2|C3, X1)}$

And:

$P(O2|C3, X1) = P(O2|C3, X1, H)P(H|C3, X1) + P(O2|C3, X1, Hc)P(Hc|C3, X1)$

I'd appreciate some thoughts on this.

Comment: Well.... did you try plugging in some numbers?  It seems like a straightforward Baye's theorem.

Comment: Don't think you need to worry about probability that contestant picks door i.  We are given that he picked door 1.  That's a given.

Comment: Is not the formula above incorrect? Certain factors simply cancel out? P(O2|C3,X1)P(C3|X1)/P(O2|C3,X1) = P(C3|X1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coin flip, the door that the contestant picks, and the placement of the car will be mutually independent .

However, the door that Monty picked depended on their result.   When the contestant and car indicate different doors, then if the coin landed heads, Monty *certainly* revealed the only goat he could, but otherwise he had *unbiasedly* choosen a door from *those the contestant did not choose* reguardless of the car placement.

$$\begin{split}\mathsf P(O_2\mid X_1,C_3) &= \mathsf P(H)~\mathsf P(O_2\mid H,X_1,C_3) + \mathsf P(H^\complement)~\mathsf P(O_2\mid H^\complement,X_1)\end{split}$$

Of course, if both the contestant and car choose the same door, then Monty's choiseof goats was unbiased whatever the coin may have said.

---

$$\begin{split}\mathsf P(C_3\mid X_1,O_2) &= \dfrac{\mathsf P(C_3)~\mathsf P(O_2\mid X_1,C_3)}{\mathsf P(C_1)~\mathsf P(O_2\mid X_1,C_1)+\mathsf P(C_3)~\mathsf P(O_2\mid X_1,C_3)}\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks for this, yeah, I thought about being independent events, although didn't simplify.